# Importing SVG gives error: `Attribute "android:fillType" was already specified for element "path".`

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, android-vectordrawable

Below is the SVG file contents. It was imported from Figma (design sketching app).

```
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M6.78759 8.20572L7.37223 7.62108C7.53367 7.45964 7.79542 7.45964 7.95686 7.62108L10.4589 10.1263C10.6203 10.2878 10.6203 10.5495 10.4589 10.711L9.87424 11.2956C9.71279 11.457 9.45104 11.457 9.2896 11.2956L6.78759 8.79036C6.62614 8.62892 6.62614 8.36717 6.78759 8.20572Z" fill="white"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.28759 5.70572L9.87223 5.12108C10.0337 4.95964 10.2954 4.95964 10.4569 5.12108L12.9589 7.62632C13.1203 7.78776 13.1203 8.04951 12.9589 8.21096L12.3742 8.7956C12.2128 8.95704 11.951 8.95704 11.7896 8.7956L9.28759 6.29036C9.12614 6.12892 9.12614 5.86717 9.28759 5.70572Z" fill="white"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.87424 9.54149L10.4589 10.1261C10.6203 10.2876 10.6203 10.5493 10.4589 10.7108L7.95686 13.2121C7.79542 13.3735 7.53367 13.3735 7.37223 13.2121L6.78759 12.6274C6.62614 12.466 6.62614 12.2042 6.78759 12.0428L9.2896 9.54149C9.45104 9.38005 9.71279 9.38005 9.87424 9.54149Z" fill="white"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M9.87424 5.70458L10.4589 6.28922C10.6203 6.45066 10.6203 6.71241 10.4589 6.87386L7.95686 9.37515C7.79542 9.53659 7.53367 9.53659 7.37223 9.37515L6.78759 8.79051C6.62614 8.62907 6.62614 8.36732 6.78759 8.20587L9.2896 5.70458C9.45104 5.54314 9.71279 5.54314 9.87424 5.70458Z" fill="white"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12.5 5.4165C13.1904 5.4165 13.75 4.85686 13.75 4.1665C13.75 3.47615 13.1904 2.9165 12.5 2.9165C11.8096 2.9165 11.25 3.47615 11.25 4.1665C11.25 4.85686 11.8096 5.4165 12.5 5.4165Z" fill="white"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M18.3332 13.3333C18.3332 11.4924 16.8408 10 14.9998 10C13.1589 10 11.6665 11.4924 11.6665 13.3333C11.6665 15.1743 13.1589 16.6667 14.9998 16.6667C16.8408 16.6667 18.3332 15.1743 18.3332 13.3333ZM13.3332 13.3333C13.3332 12.4129 14.0794 11.6667 14.9998 11.6667C15.9203 11.6667 16.6665 12.4129 16.6665 13.3333C16.6665 14.2538 15.9203 15 14.9998 15C14.0794 15 13.3332 14.2538 13.3332 13.3333Z" fill="white"/>
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M8.33317 13.3333C8.33317 11.4924 6.84079 10 4.99984 10C3.15889 10 1.6665 11.4924 1.6665 13.3333C1.6665 15.1743 3.15889 16.6667 4.99984 16.6667C6.84079 16.6667 8.33317 15.1743 8.33317 13.3333ZM3.33317 13.3333C3.33317 12.4129 4.07936 11.6667 4.99984 11.6667C5.92031 11.6667 6.6665 12.4129 6.6665 13.3333C6.6665 14.2538 5.92031 15 4.99984 15C4.07936 15 3.33317 14.2538 3.33317 13.3333Z" fill="white"/>
</svg>
```

Encountered inssue:
`Attribute "android:fillType" was already specified for element "path".`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in Android Studio 3.6 Beta. Try Android Studio 3.5 instead.

Comment: Same bug in 4.0 Canary 8

Comment: Works fine in 3.5. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: this bug has been fixed in AS 3.6 RC3: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/02/android-studio-36-release-candidate-3.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to `drawable` folder and right-click it: `New > Vector Asset > select .svg file > Next > Finish`.
It works for me (picture of a bicycle man).

If you have issues when you are using the image in `ImageView`, try to remove attribures `fill-rule="evenodd"` and `clip-rule="evenodd"` from the source svg and import it again.

Comment: This is exactly what I was doing and it failed.

Comment: Try to move the svg to a path that will not contain spaces. And try to import again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the "clip-rule" attributes will work around a bug (https://issuetracker.google.com/148173587) that was introduced in Android Studio 3.6 Canary 6 but didn't exist in earlier versions.

The "clip-rule" attributes have no effect in this context anyway. https://drafts.fxtf.org/css-masking-1/#the-clip-rule says: "The clip-rule property only applies to graphics elements that are contained within a clipPath element."